# Join multiple excel files into one excel file via python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, join

I need to combine all the excel files in my directory into one excel file.
for example, I've 3 excel files:

**file1:**

[image]

**file 2:**

[image]

**file 3:**

[image]

I need to concatenate them and get an output as follows

[image]

but instead, they were appended one after another
this is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('C:/Users/test-results/FinalResult/05-01-2019/*.xlsx'):
   df = pd.read_excel(f)
   all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('mycollected_data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
all_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

during my quest, all I found was how to append dfs,as shown in my code and I didn't figure out how too use `join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/test-results/FinalResult/05-01-2019/*.xlsx')
dfs = (pd.read_excel(f, index_col=0) for f in files)
all_data = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you but the generated excel file repeated the column name 3 times, so instead of having 4 columns, I have six columns.

Comment: thank you, but I meant that my output like that: `Nombre de reboot 0 Nombre de reboot 0 Nombre de reboot 0`
`Passage en mode privé 1 Passage en mode privé 1 Passage en mode privé 1`

Comment: Yep, I think I understand the intention; as `pd.concat` behaves well with respect to indices, you should be able to get that by specifying the given column as an index while reading; I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`all_data = pd.concat([all_data,df],axis=1)`

Comment: thank you but the generated excel file repeated the column name 3 times, so instead of having 4 columns, I have six columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_data = all_data.merge(df, on = ['first_column_name'], how = 'left')
```

Comment: or how = 'inner'

Comment: thank you for your answer but it generated an empty df

Comment: Sorry, You can try merge to replace join.